# Sum of numbers in a string not working properly

Tags: java, string

I have a string, which contains numbers and characters and special symbols. But I need to calculate sum of digits inside a string.
suppose my string is

```
String input = "step@12test_demo,9,8*#1234/add2doe";
```

result should be 12+9+8+1234+2=1265 but for my code I'm getting result as 1+2+9+8+1+2+3+4+2=32. This is my code

```
public class sumOfNumInString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "step@12test_demo,9,8*#1234/add2doe";
        String output = "";
        int temp = input.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < temp; i++) {
            Character c = input.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                output = output + c;
            }
        }
        int result = Integer.parseInt(output);
        System.out.println(result);
        int num = result, sum = 0, r;
        for (; num != 0; num = num / 10) {
            r = num % 10;
            sum = sum + r;
        }
        System.out.println("Sum of digits of number: " + sum);//32
        //Need output as :12+9+8+1234+2=  1265
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to identify the sequences of numbers to add, as you are adding individual characters as numbers at the moment. Matching the string with a regular expression to extract the numbers and then parsing and adding them should work.

```
private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+");

public static int total(String input) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
    int total = 0;

    while (matcher.find()) {
        total += Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(0));
    }

    return total;
}
```

This returns 1265 when called with your input string.

Thanks to Francesco for the tip!

Comment: The pattern could also be written as: `\\d+`. Then the while loop becomes `while (m.find()) {
       int current = Integer.parseInt(m.group());
       total += current;
   }`

Comment: Nice improvement. TBH I should have looked for that implementation from the start - perl and similar have easy ways to get every match from a string in a single call.

Comment: Last thing to do is to get rid of the `current` variable.

Comment: You should move out your Pattern compilation from method and place it in class field (probably even static one) to avoid compiling this pattern each time method or constructor is invoked. Because people don't do this simple improvements regex is in most cases wrongly considered as very slow :/

Answer (score 0):

You should join your consecutive digits. You could build a string with number and operations and after that, analyze it.

```
String res = "";
for (int i = 0; i < temp; i++) {
        Character c = input.charAt(i);
        if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
            res  += c.toString();
        }else{
             if(! (res.charAt(res.length() - 1).equals('+')) ) res+= '+';                
           }
    }
```

Now you can parse you String res with a StringTokenizer

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer("+ ");

int sum = 0;
String number = "";


while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {

number = st.nextToken();

sum += Integer.parseInt(number);


}
```

Comment: Not a good answer, regular expressions can avoid all of this. Look at @Matthew Franglen answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not interested in regex solution you can simply iterate over all characters and if it is digit add it to buffer which will contain all continues digits. When current character is not digit we need to reset buffer and handle its earlier contend (include its currently stored number to sum). To do this you can chose to concatenate your char to String. Easiest and preferred way to do it is with StringBuilder.

```
public static int sumOfNumbers(String input) {
    int sum = 0;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (char ch : input.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isDigit(ch)) {
            sb.append(ch); //add character to buffer -> "12"+'3'= "123"
        } else if (sb.length() > 0) {
            sum += Integer.parseInt(sb.toString());//increase sum based on current number
            sb.delete(0, sb.length()); // reset buffer for new number
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Usage

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    String input = "step@12test_demo,9,8*#1234/add2doe";
    System.out.println("Sum of numbers: " + sumOfNumbers(input));// 1265
}
```

Output:

```
Sum of numbers: 1265
```